# Segmentation fault in printing a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

It is a simple program which takes 5 elements from the user and prints it. But it is showing a segmentation fault at line 30. Please help. Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
int num;
struct node * next;
};

main()
{
int i;
struct node *p,*temp,*r;
p=NULL;
temp=p;
temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
scanf("%d",&(temp->num));
temp->next=NULL;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    temp=temp->next;
    r=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    scanf("%d",&(r->num));  
    r->next=NULL;
    temp->next=r;
}
temp=p;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",temp->num);
    temp=temp->next;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
struct node *p,*temp,*r;
p=NULL;
```

Subsequent code never sets `p` to a non-null value.  You then use:

```
temp=p;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",temp->num);
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

So you're dereferencing a null pointer. This leads to unhappiness and crashes.

1. Rename `p` to something like `root` or `head` to indicate its important role as the start of the list.
2. Assign the pointer to the first element of the list to the newly renamed variable.

For example, instead of:

```
temp=p;
temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

use (without renaming):

```
p = temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

or:

```
p = temp = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

Also, you should error check the `malloc()` and `scanf()` calls; both can fail.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
temp=p;       // p is NULL!!
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",temp->num);   // <-- BANG!
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

you are reassigning `temp` as `p` which is previously declared as NULL. Thus you are dereferencing a NULL pointer. Looking at your code, you probably do not even need `p` as you 
only ever use to initialise `temp` to NULL at the very beginning.

Comment: actually p is my head pointer so that i do not lose the point of beginning of the list..

Answer (score 2):

A simple change in your main function that's all , the problem is temp=p=NULL and then making null point to num in printf("%d\n",temp->num);

so your main should  be like this

```
main()
{
int i;
struct node *p,*temp,*r;
temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
p=temp;
scanf("%d",&(temp->num));
temp->next=NULL;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    temp=temp->next;
    r=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    scanf("%d",&(r->num));
    r->next=NULL;
    temp->next=r;
}
temp=p;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
printf("%d\n",temp->num);
temp=temp->next;
}

}
```